# Specify highlight color for each checkbox

Tags: css

I have 3 check box. When one checkbox clicked record of table should be highlighted in red. when second checkbox clicked record of table should be highlighted in green and when third checkbox clicked record of table should be highlighted in yellow. I have the code to highlighted record with yellow. Can somebody helps me with other two. How can I specify color for each checkbox?

```
.highlight {
    background-color: yellow;
}     

<div class="col-lg-10">
    <table id="Table" border="1">
        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="cb1" id="cb1" value="y" /></td>
        <td>Click me</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="cb2" id="cb2" value="y" /></td>
        <td>Click me</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="cb3" id="cb3" value="y" /></td>
        <td>Click me</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Why dont you use javascript onchange property for this?

Comment: How can I use that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this, Of-course you can optimize that but you can see how it is done with javascript using jquery

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<style>
.highlight-red {
    background-color: red;
}    
.highlight-green {
    background-color: green;
}
.highlight-yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
}    
</style>
<div class="col-lg-10">
    <table id="Table" border="1">
        <tr class="highlight">
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="cb1" id="cb1" value="y" onChange="changeSoma(this, 'red')" /></td>
        <td>Click me</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="cb2" id="cb2" value="y" onChange="changeSoma(this, 'green')" /></td>
        <td>Click me</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="cb3" id="cb3" value="y" onChange="changeSoma(this, 'yellow')" /></td>
        <td>Click me</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 
 function changeSoma(data, color){
   if(data.checked && color == 'red'){
    $(data).parent().parent().addClass("highlight-red");
   }
   else{
    $(data).parent().parent().removeClass("highlight-red");
   }
   if(data.checked && color == 'green'){
    $(data).parent().parent().addClass("highlight-green");
   }
   else{
    $(data).parent().parent().removeClass("highlight-green");
   }
   if(data.checked && color == 'yellow'){
    $(data).parent().parent().addClass("highlight-yellow");
   }
   else{
    $(data).parent().parent().removeClass("highlight-yellow");
   }
 }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I up-vote your answer mr.Darkseid. Can you explain me, Is there any way to keep the clicked result as same even during page refreshment? Now I am trying to do that part

Comment: you can save the clicked value with cookies and just grab the cookie every time the user opens the page

Answer (score 0):

you'll do as follow:

```
.cb3 {background-color:yellow;}
.cb2 {background-color:green;}
.cb1 {background-color:red;}
```

and then the JS (using jquery per example)

```
$('#cb3').onclick(function(){
$(your table).addClass('cb3');
});
```

this will color the table depending on the clicked element, if cliucking on cb3 then it will apply the cb3 class (that has yelllow background)

Comment: Thank you Mr.Sletheren. Unfortunately it did not work. I edited my question including code in full length. Can you please see it and give me a solution?